# How do I make a specific word uneditable in Slate.js?

Tags: reactjs, slatejs

I'm creating a rich text editor for my application. The content, is generated automatically from a template which may contain variables. What I am trying to achieve here is, I want to be able to make a specific word uneditable in the editor. To be clear, allow me to describe my situation in detail:

Say there's a template:

```
Hello {name}, welcome to {location}!
```

And the data looks like this:

```
{
    "name": "John Doe",
    "location": "Bangi Wonderland",
}
```

As result of parsing the template with the data above, it should look like this:

```
Hello John Doe, welcome to Bangi Wonderland!
```

Now, I'm trying to make the content above editable, but user should not be allowed to update the substituted variables such as `John Doe` and `Bangi Wonderland` directly in the editor. The idea is to wrap those words in a `<span>` and make it uneditable, but I don't exactly know how to.

How can I achieve this in Slate.js?

Comment: Hello, I am also wondering if this is possible, did you found a solution?

Answer (score 0):

Use property: `contentEditable={false}` in element renderer

[Source](https://github.com/ianstormtaylor/slate/blob/42b60fb0eb34c177094d4c4ba01121945f17ec90/site/examples/images.tsx#L108)

[Slate Examples with this props](https://www.slatejs.org/examples/images)